# Método delete retorna página não econtrada

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Utilizo o form abaixo para enviar o id da linha a ser deletada na tabela:

```
<form method="DELETE" action="{{ URL::to('receitas/delete') }}" >

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $receita->id }}" >

<button type="submit" class="button-deletar" ></button>

</form>
```

---

O meu controller tem a seguinte function:

```
public function getDestroy($id){

  // delete
  $receita = Receita::find($id);
  $receita->delete();

  // SALVANDO LOG
  $logger = Helper::salvaLog("receitas",$id,"exclusao");    

  // redirect
  Session::flash('message', 'Receita excluída com sucesso!');
  return Redirect::to('receitas');
}
```

---

O routes está assim:

```
Route::controller('receitas', 'ReceitaController');

Route::delete('receitas/{id}', ReceitaController@getDestroy );
```

---

Porque retorna 404 página não encontrada ( `local/receitas/7` )?

Answer (score 4):

O problema em seu formulário está em como o `method` foi definido.

Os HTML formulários em HTML só [suportam os métodos `POST` e `GET`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162960/should-put-and-delete-be-used-in-forms). Em contrapartida o HTTP possui outros métodos, como o `DELETE`, `PUT` e `PATH`.

Alguns frameworks, como o Laravel por exemplo, conhecendo essa limitação do HTML, implementam um campo `input` do tipo `hidden` para traduzirem a requisição desejada para a rota correta da aplicação.

No caso do Laravel, ao utilizar o [recurso de `Form::open()`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form) ele automaticamente adicionará um `hidden` com o nome `_method`, que é como o Laravel trata essa conversão.

Ou seja, para deletar de forma correta a receita da sua aplicação, você tem duas escolhas:

1. Converter seu form e utilizar `Form::open()`

   ```
   {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'receitas', 'method' => 'DELETE')) }}

       <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $receita->id }}" >
       <button type="submit" class="button-deletar" ></button>

   {{ Form::close() }}
   ```
2. Adicionar um `hidden` com nome `_method` no seu formulário

   ```
   <form action="{{ URL::to('receitas') }}" method="POST">
       <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" >    
       <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $receita->id }}" >

       <button type="submit" class="button-deletar" ></button>

   </form>
   ```

Comment: Caro gmsantos, realizei as alterações como você sugeriu e ainda não consegui deletar do banco de dados, porém o retorno não é mais página não encontrada e sim a url: local/receitas?_method=DELETE&id=7

Comment: @CleitonHatsu vc usou o form do laravel ou a segunda opção? tente alterar o método do form para post, como a resposta editada.

Answer (score -1):

O problema está na sua rota, você especificou apenas:

`Route::delete('receitas/{id}', ReceitaController@getDestroy );`

Quando na verdade deveria ser:

`Route::delete('receitas/delete/{id}', ReceitaController@getDestroy );`

Porém você está passando por parâmetro via DELETE no seu HTML/form, e não pegando o id como parâmetro pela URL, como a routa está fazendo.

Ou seja, você deve apontar para essas rotas, como por ex:

`receitas/delete/12313` <- deleta a receita de id "12313"

`receitas/delete/12` <- deleta a receita de id "12"

Comment: Em complemento a essa resposta, eu apenas diria que associar uma rota `/receitas/delete/{id}` é um tanto redundante, já que o verbo HTTP `DELETE` já diz o que deve ser feito. O ideal seria fazer um `DELETE /receitas/{id}`.

Comment: Mesmo assim a rota delete não seria disparada, pois falta a passagem do método `delete` no form HTML via `_method`